# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) - LARAVEL 8

Tags: php, laravel, http-status-code-404

I have a problem with my routes on the server and using laravel 8, with a version of php 8.0.6
When developing locally I have no problem with the routes, everything is normal, but when uploading the project to the server (to which I do not have access but someone else uploads the changes from the repository) it throws me the following error in some views...
[Error 404](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUSzV.png)

In my code I have the routes declared as follows in the routes/web.php file...

`Route::get('/home', 'PagesController@home');`

Each view has a function that comes from the controller...

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use PhpParser\Node\Expr\FuncCall;

class PagesController extends Controller
{
public function home()
    {
        $page_title = 'Dashboard';
        return view('pages.dashboard', compact('page_title'));
    }
}
```

On the other hand, each route can be accessed through a menu aside

```
// Aside menu
return [

    'items' => [
        // Dashboard
        [
            'title' => 'Dashboard',
            'root' => true,
            'icon' => 'media/svg/icons/Design/Layers.svg', // or can be 'flaticon-home' or any flaticon-*
            'page' => '/home',
            'new-tab' => false,
        ]
 ]
]
```

I tried :

1. correct writing to avoid mistakes
2. change "/" in each affected path

note: they told me the server was in strict mode

Comment: Maybe it's because on the server routes might be cached.

Comment: @shaedrich should I clear the cache on the server?

Comment: Yep, I would give that a try.